# Google Cloud: Cannot create static IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am tryign to create a static IP address using the google cloud console terminal:

```
gcloud compute addresses create helloweb-ip --region us-central1
```

It returns with:

```
Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<project-name>-409407/regions/us-central1/addresses/helloweb-ip]
```

Which if followed returns the following json:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Login Required.",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "required",
                "location": "Authorization",
                "locationType": "header"
            }
        ],
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
                "domain": "googleapis.com",
                "metadatas": {
                    "service": "compute.googleapis.com",
                    "method": "compute.v1.RegionAddressesService.Get"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Not sure why this isn't working, but I can't figure out why it isn't. As near as I can tell, I am logged into the gcloud console app. I have been using `gcloud` command from the terminal in the Cloud console, not from any locally configured device, so I assume it's been configured correctly.

Comment: Hi `Kirk Sefchik` have you gone through my answer, kindly revert back if you are still facing some issues.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, after opening the gcloud cli from the console you are directly trying to execute gcloud commands for creating the static IP address. There is a prerequisite which needs to be satisfied before you run any command as mentioned in this [official documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#gcloud) It starts with the title **“Before you begin”**, in this section they have mentioned the following command

```
gcloud init
```

First you need to execute this command even if you have opened gcloud cli from the console. It will help you in authenticating your google cloud account and configuring your project in which you want to deploy resources.

Update:
The error which you are getting is not related to the creation of static IP, if you search IP addresses or under VPC menu if you go to IP address tab you can see your IP got created.

[image]

The error we are seeing is related to viewing the response which got generated after the static IP got generated, since we are going curl a google api we need to use authentication for viewing the Json response as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/how-tos/api-requests-responses)

Comment: As I mentioned, this is being done directly from the google cloud console. Typing `gcloud init` doesn't do anythign in this environment and in this case produces an error saying it's not nescessary.

Comment: @KirkSefchik My bad I think you might have already setup the project in the gcloud cli and the error in the Json body which you are seeing is related to viewing the googleapi response but not related IP reservation itself. please go through the updated answer.